# Uploaded Article projects not uploading in my Report project and therefore my Table of Context not appearing

Tags: table-of-contents, input, overleaf, article, report

I am writing a thesis and I am using Overleaf. I have upload all the chapter from different articles to make up the chapters in my thesis. For some very strange reason, only one

\chapter{...}
\input{...}

work, in this case, only the introduction works, all the other chapters are not inputed into my project. Please, if anyone knowns how I can fix this, will be grateful. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You might want to tag this with overleaf. As always are you sure your overleaf project actually compiles with no errors? May users seems to ignore the compilation errors

Comment: Additionally are you 100% sure about the file casing of the files you're inputting

Comment: No errors in compiling.

Comment: We have no idea what class you are using, neither do we know what your preamble looks like. Perhaps this information might help.

Comment: File content doesn't just disappear. Can you open the various chapter files in overleaf and do they have the correct contents? If it does then we'd like to see the contents of the compilation log. Additionally please don't post images of code we cannot use that for much

Comment: the log file will show the reason for lack of output, show the log from that example

Comment: The location of the log file on Overleaf (which @DavidCarlisle meant), where the errors may appear is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLQaF.png).